# How can I get access token for server, if I use Games.API in Android?

Tags: android, api, google-play-services

In my Android game I use Google Services for achievements and save game data. My Google Api Client:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(StartActivity.this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(StartActivity.this)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content))
                .build();
```

Now I need to use google authorization with my server. I read google documentation(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) and try to realize this. I add `.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, geo)`to my google api client. If I use this Api then I can get idToken for verification on server side. But I get an error "Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API cannot be used with Games.API". Searching the Internet, I found that I should use only Games.API. How I found on Google developers blog (http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html), this code is good:

```
GetServerAuthCodeResult result = Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(gac, clientId).await();  
if (result.isSuccess()) {  
    String authCode = result.getCode();  
    // Send code to server.  
}
```

But `GetServerAuthCodeResult` and `getGamesServerAuthCode` are deprecated. And `result.getCode()` always return `null` for me. What way is good to get token for server side authentication and also use Games.API for achievements?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The beat wat to go about this is once the player is authenticated on the device:
Get an auth code to send to your backend server:

```
GetServerAuthCodeResult result =
Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(gac, clientId).await();
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    String authCode = result.getCode(); 
        // Send code to server.
}
```

On the server, exchange the auth code received for a token by making an RPC to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token to exchange the auth code for an access token.
You’ll have to provide the server client ID, server client secret (listed in the Developer Console when you created the server client ID), and the auth code. See more details [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer?utm_campaign=play%20games_discussion_permissions_012316&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#handlingresponse)

Once you have the access token, the player's ID is retrieved using: www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications//verify/ using the access token. Pass the auth token in a header as follows: `Authorization: OAuth`

The response value will contain the player ID for the user. This is the correct player ID to use for this user. This access token can be used to make additional server-to-server calls as needed.

Comment: result.getCode()  always return null for me. May be I should add anything in my google api client? For example, if I use GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API then I should add "requestIdToken".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, `result.getCode()` always returned `null` for me as well. It turned out that I had forgotten to create and link an app of type `Web`  under the Google Developer Console linked-apps. With both the `Android`-type and the `Web`-type in place and using its complete Client ID, when calling `getGamesServerAuthCode(gac, clientId)`, did the trick.